# Html.DropDownList default selected item

Tags: razor, html-select, razor-2

I am displaying a list of dropDownLists inside a `ForEach` loop.

This is the code

```
@foreach (var task in Model.TaskList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ModuleID", new SelectList(Model.ModuleList, "ModuleID", "Ordre"))
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I want the `Module` of each `Task` to be selected by default. This could easily be done using `DropDownList` if only I was binding the dropDownList to a view model, but that's not the case.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This could easily be done using DropDownList if only I was binding the
>   dropDownList to a view model

You already know the correct answer and are still asking the question. And are still not using a view model.

What else can I say, you could pass the value of the element that you want preselected as 4th argument of the `SelectList` constructor:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ModuleID", 
    new SelectList(Model.ModuleList, "ModuleID", "Ordre", task.ModuleID)
)
```

Comment: Well that was easy, I wonder why I haven't think of that. Thanks!